# How to access Emberjs Model Data inside a Route

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I would like to access all data of say a (`Message` model with `value` and `author` properties) inside a route or controller, do something with them, and then store them to an HTML localStorage. However, all of the examples I have seen so far use `each controller` to access every model data on Handlebars. The following is my pseudo-implementation.

```
App.MessagesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  setupController: function(controller, model) {

    messages = this.get('store').find('message') 
    //^This returns a PromiseArray but I can't seem to access the actual values.
    //I also tried messages.forEach but it doesn't seem to work

    //...
    //...

    //Below is what I'd like to do, to push the messages into the localStorage
    //Therefore I'd like `messages` to be an array
    for (var i=0; i<messages.length; i++)
      localStorage.setItem('messages', JSON.stringify(messages[i]))
  }
});
```

I know I'm just missing something simple here. But I just couldn't find it on the docs.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to wait for the promise array to fulfill and then iterate over it like this:

```
App.MessagesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  setupController: function(controller, model) {

    messages = this.get('store').find('message') 

    messages.then(function() {
       messages.forEach(function(message) {
          // do what ya like
       });
    });
});
```

See the [PromiseArray docs](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.PromiseArray.html) and [forEach docs](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Enumerable.html#method%5fforEach).

Comment: Ohh! I used `.forEach` but I didn't know I just need to use the `.then` function too :D Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The Ember way is to first setup the model in your route and Ember will only call setupController after the promise has resolved (ie after the model(s) have been fetched).

```
App.MessagesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.get('store').find('message');
  },
  setupController: function(controller, model) {
    model.forEach(function(msg) {
      // save message to localStorage here
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Ohh... Thanks! This is definitely a better approach :) Although, I'll be sticking with NicholasJohn's answer for now since I'm calling the `messages.then(function() {
       messages.forEach(function(message) {` for a few times in the `processing` part of the code